# SPARQL generate Values for missing fields

Tags: sparql, rdf

I´m trying to write a SELECT, that gives me all the Values in a Table. I have optional Values, I want those to be filled with a standard value, If they don´t exist.

This is my code:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
?a nmo:hasObject nm:coin 
OPTIONAL
{ ?a nmo:hasAuthority ?b }
OPTIONAL
{ ?a nmo:hasMaterial ?c }}
```

What I get id the following:

```
?a ?b ?c
1  yx 
2     ab
3  xz bc
```

What I want is to fill it up with the String "missing" if there is no value:

```
?a ?b        ?c
1  yx        "missing"
2  "missing"  ab
3  xz         bc
```

Any ideas on how to structure the SELECT to get this output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd probably use [**coalesce**](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-coalesce) here:

```sql
SELECT
  ?a
  (coalesce (?b, ?missing) as ?bb)
  (coalesce (?c, ?missing) as ?cc)
WHERE {
  VALUES ?missing { "missing" }
  ?a nmo:hasObject nm:coin 
  OPTIONAL
  { ?a nmo:hasAuthority ?b }
  OPTIONAL
  { ?a nmo:hasMaterial ?c }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

SPARQL 1.1 `BIND` in combination with `IF` can be used to achieve this:

```sql
 SELECT * WHERE
  { ?a  nmo:hasObject  nm:coin
    OPTIONAL
      { ?a  nmo:hasAuthority  ?b_tmp }
    OPTIONAL
      { ?a  nmo:hasMaterial  ?c_tmp }
    BIND(if(bound(?b_tmp), ?b_tmp, "missing") AS ?b)
    BIND(if(bound(?c_tmp), ?c_tmp, "missing") AS ?c)
  }
```

Comment: I´ve tried this but I got a parse exception, I deleted the second } after ?c, but it´s still there.

Comment: Ah, sorry - I forgot to assign the variables. Fixed now. But the answer from JoshuaTaylor is indeed more compact :D